# Why are gluons necessary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

I understand that quarks are attracted to each other when they have different color charges to become neutral. I also understand that gluons are the exchange particles of the strong force by switching the color charge of two quarks, but why are they necessary? If the color charge of quarks never changed, wouldn't they still be attracted to each other and bind together to form baryons?

Comment: Because in the Standard Model each interaction is mediated by a gauge boson.

Comment: Interactions between elementary particles are due to the exchange of gauge bosons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The microcosm of particles is modeled with quantum mechanical tools, and particular quantum field theory is used to model interactions. Interactions need the exchanged bosons by construction of the theories.

Take the simple interaction of an electron with another electron, which classically is described with fields and the forces between charges. At the micro level the following feynman diagrams allow to calculate the interaction [between the two particles,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)

[image: e-e-]

The virtual photon carries the force of the interaction, the dp/dt.

This is  the first order diagram in a perturbative expansion, the higher order terms give a much  smaller contribution.

One does not use feynman diagrams to calculate the binding of an electron to a proton so as to produce a hydrogen atom, because the quantum mechanical equations can be solved analytically, and the energies are not very high, but the binding of the electron to the proton is due to the exchanges of photons between them.

So at the micro level there is always the need of an exchanged particle.

Quarks are never free, they were discovered because of symmetries in the [hadronic resonances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)) produced in scattering experiments, first seen after the midlle of last century. The need of a strong interaction which does not allow freedom for quarks  at our laboratory energies led to proposing QCD , where the exchanged particles carry a charge also (the photon has zero charge) which gives rise to the strong attractive force.

[image: gluons]

> Gluon interactions are often represented by a Feynman diagram. Note that the gluon generates a color change for the quarks. The gluons are in fact considered to be bi-colored, carrying a unit of color and a unit of anti-color as suggested in the diagram at right. The gluon exchange picture there converts a blue quark to a green one and vice versa. The range of the strong force is limited by the fact that the gluons interact with each other as well as with quarks in the context of quark confinement. These properties contrast them with photons, which are massless and of infinite range. The photon does not carry electric charge with it, while the gluons do carry the "color charge".

Your question :

> If the color charge of quarks never changed, wouldn't they still be attracted to each other and bind together to form baryons?

gets the answer "no" , because there would be no carrier of the interaction for binding. If there were no photons, neither the hydrogen atom would exist.

Zero color gluons would not mathematically be able to build up the strong force, i.e. the attraction growing [stronger with distance within a hadron..](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/color.html#c1)

The particular model SU(3)_colorxSU(2)_weakxU(1)_electromagnetic developed by fitting the data in a unified mathematical frame which fits known data and is predictive of new data, the [standard model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)